# How can I create custom page titles for blog articles?

Tags: seo

I can specify custom page titles by editing menu options and editing Page Display -> Browser Page Title but how do I do this for blog articles which do not have individual menu options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me a bit to realize what you were asking. This thread is I think what you're talking about:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=696287

one option is to override the output of the category items, but it might be easier to just us a plugin like this one:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/meta-data/17926

Comment: Exactly, there is no way to specify without one of many SEO plugins.

Comment: In the Joomla forum post **garthjones69** suggests: "_you could make the article name in the format you want the page title to be and then choose the option to hide the article title and then put in a different title within the article content_" which will work. "Easy Frontend SEO" also looks like it will do the job and the data is stored in core tables which is nice. Thanks for a great answer!

Answer (score 3):

Create a system menu linking to the items, with prefered page titles.

Comment: This would be my suggestion, post add a menu item for any you want to custom name. The logic being that if its a blog post you wont be doing custom titles as much as for main menu items

Answer (score -1):

What version of J are you using Neil, and are you using the native J blog option or K2 or another variety of blog?

Comment: you should really post a question like that as a comment on the question not an answer, not to be all moderator

Comment: I'm referring to core Joomla functionality. This question applies to Joomla 2.5 and Joomla 3.x and probably previous versions as well.

Comment: Thank you TristanBailey. I was trying to get clarification on Neil's question to see if I had an answer for his question.

Comment: "Clarification" questions should go as comments on the question (in this area) - then you can post an "official" answer after you've received your clarification. It helps users sort through actual answers.