# Creating unique page titles for blog pages

Tags: seo

How do I set unique page titles for blog pages like these?

/news?limitstart=0
/news?start=3
/news?start=6

These are pages of blog articles from my blog page on my site.

Comment: You can set the title programmatically anytime in the lifecycle, but what do you want to set it to? And ... why?

Comment: My SEO tools show these pages as having duplicate titles (I realize it's because they are linked to a menu item for which I have specified the title in question)...but I want search engines to crawl & index these pages, but want to avoid penalty of duplicate titles. I saw this page, but didn't see a good answer: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/119/how-can-i-create-custom-page-titles-for-blog-articles

Answer (score 1):

If this menu item is a list of all the blog articles you can simple add canonical tags that will alleviate the duplicate content. Then add unique page titles once you are actually reading the article itself. You will have to dig around and see where you can add this code. You may be able to use something like the FlexiCode Module and publish it into a debug position to add these head links. You will also have to dig around to get your components pagination variable.

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addHeadLink(JURI::current().(($this->pagination->pagesCurrent > 1)?'?start='.($this->pagination->limitstart):''), 'canonical');
if($this->pagination->limitstart - $this->pagination->limit == 0){
    $doc->addHeadLink(JUri::current(), 'prev');
}else{
    if($this->pagination->limitstart - $this->pagination->limit > 0){
        $doc->addHeadLink(JUri::current().'?start='.($this->pagination->limitstart - $this->pagination->limit), 'prev');
    }
}
if($this->pagination->pagesTotal > 1){
    $doc->addHeadLink(JUri::current().'?start='.($this->pagination->pagesCurrent * $this->pagination->limit), 'next');
}
```